# join 2 tables and only display the max values for a id - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables that hold information about a drawing that I join in my query. The first table contains the drawings unique number, title and who it was drawn by. The second table contains the revision and the date the drawing was revised.

Table 1

```
|dwg_id|project_no|sws_dwg_no|dwg_title|dwg_by|
|1     |153       |153-100   |Pipe...  |JS    |
```

Table 2

```
|dwg_id|dwg_rev|dwg_date            |rev_id|
|1     |A      |2015-07-15 11:00:00 |1     |
|1     |B      |2015-07-23 12:00:00 |2     |
|1     |C      |2015-08-06 10:00:00 |3     |
```

I want join the two tables and only show the most recent revision change for a drawing.

This is my current query.

```
SELECT 
    `drawings`.`dwg_id`, 
    `project_no`, 
    `sws_dwg_no`, 
    `client_dwg_no`, 
    `dwg_title`, 
    `dwg_by`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_date`, 
    MAX(`dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`) AS dwg_rev 
FROM 
    (`drawings`) 
    JOIN `dwg_rev` ON `drawings`.`dwg_id` = `dwg_rev`.`dwg_id` 
WHERE 
    `project_no` = '153' 
GROUP BY 
    `sws_dwg_no`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev` 
ORDER BY 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_date` ASC, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev` ASC
```

The results that this query returns doesn't contain the latest revision numbers or it returns all the revision for each drawing.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple drawings per project exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT d.*, dr.*
FROM drawings AS d
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT dwg_id, MAX(rev_id) AS maxRevId
   FROM dwg_rev
   GROUP BY dwg_id
) AS t ON d.dwg_id = t.dwg_id   
INNER JOIN dwg_rev AS dr ON t.dwg_id = dr.dwg_id AND t.maxRevId = dr.rev_id
WHERE project_no = 153
```

The key point in the above query is the usage of a derived table that returns the latest revision, i.e. `MAX(rev_id)`, per `dwg_id`. Using an `INNER JOIN` on that derived table you get back exactly this row out of `dwg_rev` table.

Using something like the above is necessary if you have *multiple* `dwg_id` per `project_no`. In this case, the above query will fetch the most recent revision per drawing for `project_no = 153`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcd7b/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly the result that I wanted my query to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the latest revision you should order DESC check code below.

and also you can order only by dwg_rev`.`rev_id` DESC , if this rev_id is populated.

`SELECT` 
drawings`.`dwg_id`,` 
project_no`,` 
sws_dwg_no`,` 
client_dwg_no`,` 
dwg_title`,` 
dwg_by`,` 
dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`,` 
dwg_rev`.`dwg_date`, 
    MAX(`dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`) AS dwg_rev 
FROM 
    (`drawings`) 
    JOIN`dwg_rev`ON`drawings`.`dwg_id`=`dwg_rev`.`dwg_id
`WHERE` 
project_no`= '153' 
GROUP BY` 
sws_dwg_no`,` 
dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev
`ORDER BY` 
dwg_rev`.`dwg_date`DESC,` 
dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`DESC
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: If he only want a single result ( The latest ) you need to add a `LIMIT 1` at the end of this

Comment: @Nick Thanks that helped to get all the results, but I want the query to return only the latest revision and date for the drawings in a project.

Comment: you welcome, Yep, the other answer 2  limits 1 records i think that helped you!

Comment: aslo you can use rev_id to order your records if it is Key field that would give you latest record inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `MAX` isn't the best way to go, instead use `LIMIT`  Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `drawings`.`dwg_id`, 
    `project_no`, 
    `sws_dwg_no`, 
    `client_dwg_no`, 
    `dwg_title`, 
    `dwg_by`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_date`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev` AS dwg_rev 
FROM 
    (`drawings`) 
    JOIN `dwg_rev` ON `drawings`.`dwg_id` = `dwg_rev`.`dwg_id` 
WHERE 
    `project_no` = '153' 
GROUP BY 
    `sws_dwg_no`, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev` 
ORDER BY 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_date` DESC, 
    `dwg_rev`.`dwg_rev` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```